# Matrix resolvent identity $R_{A+B}=(I-R_AB)^{-1}R_A$

Tags: linear-algebra, generating-functions, laplace-transform

Suppose $R_M$ is the resolvent of matrix $M$ defined as $R_M=(sI-M)^{-1}$. How do I show the following?

$$R_{A+B}=(I-R_AB)^{-1}R_A$$

Is this a well known result?

I got this formula by using grouping technique in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654692/998) and checked [numerically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282684/generating-function-for-abn-in-terms-of-generating-functions-for-an-b) but wondering if theres an easier way.

Comment: I think this is well-known as the [second resolvent identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_formalism#Resolvent_identity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $R_A$, we have $(sI - A)R_A B = B$. Subtract both sides of this from $sI - A$, and we get
\begin{align}
   sI - A - (sI - A)R_A B &= sI - A - B \\
   (sI - A)(I - R_A B) &= sI - A - B \\
   (I - R_A B)^{-1} (sI - A)^{-1} &= (sI - A - B)^{-1} \\
   (I - R_A B)^{-1} R_A &= R_{A+B}
\end{align}